# Receive an error while trying to change Azure DevOps Group permissions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions

I see an error (see image) when I try to change the permissions for Groups in my Azure DevOps Services project. Not sure what is causing this since it does not shows inheritance error as well. I want to change the setting from 'Allow' to 'Not Set' or 'Disable'

[image: Azure DevOps Groups Permission error]

Comment: Hi Archie. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve? Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer*.

Answer (score 0):

We do not need to save changes after permission changed right now. When you try to change the permission by selecting different value in the dropdown from web portal. It will show **"in progress"** first, and finally **"saved"** if permission changed succeed.

[image]

In your scenario, please first kindly check if you have enough permission to change other groups' corresponding permission.

If you do, also give a try with clearing browser cache or use another browser, then change it again.

If you still get same error after all above steps, you could also use *F12* to check whether there are more detail error info for further troubleshooting.